# extract water and refill water tank

Tags: java, methods, getter-setter, getter, setter

I wrote a class Watertank and now I want to write a short loop (10-times) test programm which extracts water (empty water tank 0 liter) and than refills the tank back to 5000.

**I.)** I created a private member variable "water" double with 5000 (liter).
**II.)** Public getter member method "getWater" which returns the actual value of the member variable "water".
**II.II)** Public setter member method "setWater"
**III.)** Public member method "extractWater" which extracts 200 liter from the tank and returns a boolean.
"TRUE" if the tank is NOT empty, "FALSE" when the tank is empty.
**IV.)** Public member method "refillWater" which sets the member variable "water" to its original value.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWrES.png

Update:

I fixed my code and added the logic.
It seems to work, can someone review the logic, codingstyle and tell me if I worked properly regarding object orientation. I feel like my code is redundant at certain parts.

```
public class Watertank {
private double water = 5000;

public double getWater() {
    return water;
}

public void setWater(double water) {
    this.water = water;
}

public boolean extractWater() {

    if ((water <= 5000) && (water >= 200)) {
        water -= 200;
        return true;
    }
    return false;


}

public double refillWater() {
    water = 5000;

    return 0;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {


    Watertank vWater = new Watertank();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        while (vWater.water >= 0) {
            vWater.extractWater();
            System.out.println(vWater.water);
            if (vWater.water == 0) {
                vWater.refillWater();
                break;
            }


        }


    }
}
}
```

Comment: Whats the question here?

Comment: a short loop (10-times) test programm which extracts water (empty water tank 0 liter) and than refills the tank back to 5000.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code-writing service. Please state what your question is and highlight the relevant code in your post to allow someone to assist you.

Comment: Hi Cyan, I know it. I added my code at the bottom. Maybe you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

In your main method:

```
Watertank vWater = new Watertank();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    vWater.extractWater();
    System.out.println(vWater.water);
}
vWater.refillwater();
```

Comment: Error:(24, 35) java: <identifier> expected

Comment: @JoeSmith that is because, this answer is missing a semi colon at the end of `vWater.extractWater();`

Comment: Thanks Klaus, I fixed my code and added the logic. It seems to work, can you review and tell me if I worked properly regarding object orientation. I feel my code is redundant at certain parts.

Comment: My bad, just edited the code and added the semicolon 

Comment: No problem and thanks Sidak, maybe you can review my new added code. It seems to work, can someone review the logic, codingstyle and tell me if I worked properly regarding object orientation.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my code and added the logic.
It seems to work, can someone review the logic, codingstyle and tell me if I worked properly regarding object orientation. I feel like my code is redundant at certain parts.

```
public class Watertank {
private double water = 5000;

public double getWater() {
    return water;
}

public void setWater(double water) {
    this.water = water;
}

public boolean extractWater() {

    if ((water <= 5000) && (water >= 200)) {
        water -= 200;
        return true;
    }
    return false;


}

public double refillWater() {
    water = 5000;

    return 0;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {


    Watertank vWater = new Watertank();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        while (vWater.water >= 0) {
            vWater.extractWater();
            System.out.println(vWater.water);
            if (vWater.water == 0) {
                vWater.refillWater();
                break;
            }


        }


    }
}
}
```

Comment: Do you know about [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) ? Also, if this is ___not___ an answer, then I suggest that you [edit] your question and add your updated code there.